# How to copy a file/image to the clipboard in Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, clipboard

I can't find a way to copy an image or a file to the clipboard. I tried using pyperclip but it isn't able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using a shell command:

`os.system(f"xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i {path + '/image.png'}")`

It's less than ideal but it does the job.